# Moving position of country names in Rworldmap

Tags: r, maps, rworldmap

is there a way to move the position of the names of countries on maps generated with rworldmap? For instance, in the example below I would like to move the names of the central american countries so they are easier to read.

If not, I'd welcome suggestions on alternative ways to label the map.  Thanks.

```
library(rworldmap)  
df <- NULL  
df$country <- c("El Salvador","Mexico","Panama", "Nicaragua", "Costa Rica",       "Cuba", "Honduras", "Guatemala", "Venezuela")  
df$code<-c("SLV", "MEX", "PAN", "NIC", "CRI", "CUB", "HON", "GTM", "VEN")  
df$number<-c(100, 500, 200, 150, 300, 390, 140, 330, 60)  
df<-as.data.frame(df)  
sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map( df, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "code") 
mapCountryData(sPDF, nameColumnToPlot="number") 
sPDFmyCountries <- sPDF[sPDF$NAME %in% df$country,] 
mapCountryData(sPDFmyCountries, nameColumnToPlot="number", catMethod="fixedWidth", colourPalette="heat", borderCol="black",  mapTitle = ("Made Up Number"))
text(sPDFmyCountries, labels="NAME")
```

Comment: `text(sPDFmyCountries, labels="NAME")` returns `Error in as.double(y) : cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create an offset column in the spatial or standard dataframe and apply is as an argument for the position of the text label. (I had the same issue as the comment above, so I just converted the spdf into a regular df):

```
mapCountryData(sPDFmyCountries, nameColumnToPlot="number", catMethod="fixedWidth", colourPalette="heat", borderCol="black",  mapTitle = ("Made Up Number"))
df2=as.data.frame(sPDFmyCountries)
df2$latOffset=4 #4 degree offset
df2$lonOffset=4
text(df2$LON+df2$latOffset, df2$LAT+df2$lonOffset, labels=df2$country)
```

Given the arrangement of your countries mapped, I don't know if you will find a solution that will unclutter overlapping text boxes automatically that will not stray names too far from some of the smaller countries, so I am thinking you may want to tweak individual offset columns to your liking...

If you do want to find a way to declutter labels automatically, there seems to be a few resources out there:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16057/how-do-i-avoid-overlapping-labels-in-an-r-plot

Comment: Thanks Lucas! I will start with that.  Incidentally the first time I ran your suggestion it worked, then I tried to re-run my original code above and i I got the same error as @hrbrmstr above.